# Get user's telegram id from my Android app

Tags: android, uri, telegram, telegram-bot

I want to get my user's [Telegram](https://telegram.org/) Id in my android app if the user has telegram app installed on his phone. 
I supposed this can be done through a Uri if telegram supports it. If not I guess I need to figure out a way to use Telegram bot. 
I searched an and I found [this](https://telegramlogin.com/) but this over complicates things. I want a pretty streamline way of just getting the user's Id. Obviously I can ask users to input that in an EditBox but I want to remove the hassle from the user's point of view. 
Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply setup a Telegram-CLI with your mobile number on your server.

When users interact with you via their Telegram clients, you can easily get their Telegram user-ids.

Your app can then communicate with your server to get the Telegram user-ids as required

Comment: "When users interact with you via their Telegram clients, you can easily get their Telegram user-ids." can you give me more details on how to do that?

Comment: That depends... what platforms and programming languages are you comfortable with?

Comment: Im doing this on Android using Java

Comment: OK cool. so what you need is a simple Telegram  API Java library that you can use to run a Telegram Client on your server, that hosts your number. Once your customers interact with your number, that client would record all the interactions, in particular, collect their Telegram user_id as you require. Your Android app can them via HTTP access your server and get all the contacts user_id, names even contacts profile pictures if you need that directly from your server.

Comment: What do you mean client interacting with a server thats registered with my number? What sort of interaction is required? Can I do this process seamlessly like client pressing only a button to accept the server getting his username?

Comment: maybe i need to better understand your usecase